# Saving Screenshots in AWS S3 bucket using C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am developing windows application where automatically it takes screenshots and saved in AWS S3 bucket. I was able to take Screenshot and saved in my local system but struggling to save image to S3 bucket.

Here is my code

```
        double screenLeft = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenLeft;
        double screenTop = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenTop;
        double screenWidth = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth;
        double screenHeight = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight;

        string bucketName = "bucketname";
        string awsAccessKey = "AccessKey";
        string awsSecretKey = "SecretKey";
        string folderPath = "Screenshot/";
        string date = today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string folderexistcheck = folderPath + Sessions.EmpId + "/" + date + "/";
        IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.USWest2);

        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((int)screenWidth, (int)screenHeight))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                String filename = "ScreenCapture-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy-hhmmss") + ".png";
                Opacity = .0;
                g.CopyFromScreen((int)screenLeft, (int)screenTop, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
                MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
                /* Saving screenshot in local system */
                bmp.Save("C:\\screenshot\\" + filename);
                new MemoryStream(m.GetBuffer());
                Opacity = 1;

                /* this is what i tryed to save screenshot in S3 bucket */
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(bmp);
                string path = folderexistcheck;

                PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
                {
                    InputStream = file.OpenRead(),
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = path // <-- in S3 key represents a path  
                };

                PutObjectResponse response = client.PutObject(request);
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is not working? Did you get any error?

Comment: We can't help with "struggling". Read [ask], debug your code and explain to us what you expect it to do and what it actually does.

Comment: problem here is I have image in bitmap. when I am sending bmp to FileInfor file = new FileInfo(bmp) i am getting error cannot convert bitmap to string.

Comment: So you want `new FileInfo("C:\\screenshot\\" + filename)`? Also, are you sure you want to upload uncompressed bitmaps?

Comment: to be frank I am not sure what I am doing here. this is first time I am working with AWS. if you can guide me how I can save Screenshots taken directly to S3 bucket it will be helpfull

Comment: Can you save the image as Base64?